# Problem with \newcommand that mimics lstinline

Tags: macros, listings

I'm trying to replicate a part of a scanned book. Book is about programming (pure C).
I need to use many commands with a same name but with different surrounding, for example, background color etc. I'm using `listings` package. 
I created with `newcommand`, something like an alias for `\lstinline`. Later, maybe, I'll surround it with background color or different font/size or something like that. I want to be able to do this kind of things on-the-fly (to tweak every thing later easy).

Main problem is with a source code in the book (specifically *reserved* or *special* characters, like `#` or `\`). At the moment, I just use different names for a plain commands, which I'm going to define (expand) later, something like this:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}

\test{"\nA marathon is %f kilometers.\n\n"}
\lstinline{"\nA marathon is %f kilometers.\n\n"}
```

*problem* is with this command:

```
\test{"\nA marathon is %f kilometers.\n\n"}
```

while *this* command, as expected, works fine:

```
\lstinline{"\nA marathon is %f kilometers.\n\n"}
```

I get errors (`Undefined Control Sequence. \nA`), but soon as I remove (La)TeX special characters (`#`, `\`), everything runs normally.

My question is, is there a clean way to create newcommands (or an aliases) which are dealing with source code, or, there is some other, more **elegant** way that you know?

Any help apreciated.

Comment: Related: [Any ideas why this \newcommand{\n}{\lstinline|\n|} macro doesn't work?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17153)

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\test}{\lstinline}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very similar to problem the idea behind passing arguments containing verbatim content. Once an argument has been gobbled (using a definition like `\newcommand{\test}[1]`), you cannot change the category codes associated with each element of the input. As such, the verbatim interpretation is completely lost.

In your instance, the most convenient way around this would be to make `\test` do exactly what `\lstinline` does through something like

```
\let\test\lstinline
```

(perhaps safer to use `\LetLtxMacro` from [`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro); see [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764)) or

```
\newcommand{\test}{\lstinline}
```

This works since `\lstinline` doesn't gobble it's (mandatory) argument. It leaves that for processing later on. The above solution literally inserts `\lstinline` wherever it finds `\test`, providing an easy alias for `\lstinline`.

Comment: As an aside: `xparse` can also deal with this usinv `\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{v}{\lstinline{#1}}`.

Comment: Given that `\lstinline{bla $a$}` does not work but that `\lstinline|bla $a$|` does, is there anyway to get something like `\test{bla $a$}` to be replaced with `\lstinline|bla $a$|`?

Comment: @Abdallah: You *can* use `\test{bla $a$}` if you `\newcommand{\test}{\lstinline}`.

Comment: @Werner Ah ok. But then, doesn't it get replaced with `\lstinline{bla $a$}` instead of `\lstinline|bla $a$|`? Oh... perhaps I should try `\test|bla $a$|`!

Comment: @Abdallah: Yes it does, and `\lstinline` is specifically designed to work with `{`...`}`. Read the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (**4.2 Typesetting listings**, p 27: "An experimental implementation..."). However, you can also use `\test|...|`.

Comment: @Werner Yes, I have spent some time on the documentation but `\lstinline{bla $a$}` does [specifically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48371/5471) not work as I intend (in a tabular). Fortunately, `\test|bla $a$|` does the trick.