# A\b Using mcode package

Tags: matlab

How do I typeset "x=A\b" in mcode, which represents "matrix division" in MATLAB? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath, amssymb, paralist, fancybox, listings, mathtools, verbatim, textcomp}
\usepackage{mcode}
\usepackage[unicode,pdfborder={0 0 0 0}, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=red, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=small,labelsep=none]{caption}
\lstset{language=Matlab}
\begin{document}
In MATLAB, it can be solved by executing the statement \mcode{x  =  A \ b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure how to answer this.  First, you'll need the `mcode.sty` package.  Do you have that?  Second, what kind of result are you expecting from `\mcode{x = A \ b}`.  It doesn't appear that `mcode.sty` is a standard package.  But I did find a copy posted at [this site](http://web.mit.edu/~paul_s/www/14.170/matlab/mcode.sty)

Comment: @A.Ellett: Actually, [`mcode`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) is available from MathWorks.

Comment: Yes, I have mcode.sty. I use it quite a bit. \mcode{command} allows  one to have MATLAB syntax incorporated throughout ones LaTeX document quite easily. One way of solving a linear system, Ax=b in MATLAB, is through its \ operator. So, you would enter the command x=A\b to obtain the solution x. What I need help with is being able to type "\" and have it appear as it would in MATLAB.

Comment: If you *double* \ as \\, then you get the desired output.  It seems that something is getting parsed incorrectly as it's being passed from the definition of `\mcode` to the `\lstinline` command which is actually doing the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write something like

```
\mcode{x = A \\ b }
```

It seems that the better option is to redefine `\mcode` as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\mcode}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\lstbasicfont]}
```

and then it seems to work fine.

For me with this redefined `\mcode`

```
\mcode{x = A \ b}
```

gets typeset as you want.

Something in the argument is getting processed before it's getting to the `\lstinline` command.  The renewed definition allows `\lstinline` to process its arguments a bit more effectively.

Basically, `mcode.sty` defines the following

```
\newcommand{\mcode}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\lstbasicfont]|#1|}
```

If you just try something like

```
\lstinline[basicstyle=lstbasicfont]|x=A\b|
```

Then you get the result.  `listings` is doing various magic like `\verb`.  By defining the wrapper command `\mcode` not all the character codes are being processed soon enough.

See [\lstinline!Foo! vs \lstinline{Foo}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48371/22413) for how newly defined command handles the difference between

```
\mcode|x=A \ b|
```

and

```
 \mcode{x = A \ b}
```

Comment: Your solutions work for me--both redefining \mcode as well as "doubling up" the \\. Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [`matlab-prettifier` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

% Define a one-character shorthand (") for inline code.
\lstMakeShortInline[style=Matlab-editor]"

\begin{document}
"x=A\b" represents ``matrix division'' in MATLAB.
\end{document}
```